# boost::smart_ptr and COW containers

Tags: c++, boost-smart-ptr

I'm using boost::scoped_array in a container that I want to make copy-on-write but I fear that scoped_array won't work. Which boost::smart_ptr container is closest to cow-safe scoped array?

Comment: what do you mean by "won't work?" In what way don't you think it will work?

Comment: The noncopyable design may make reference aliasing more trouble than it's worth. Less work to just use shared_array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm).